# python: reading file from URL

Tags: python

What is the proper way to read text file from internet.
For example text file here https://gist.githubusercontent.com/deekayen/4148741/raw/01c6252ccc5b5fb307c1bb899c95989a8a284616/1-1000.txt

Code below works but produces extra `'b` in front of each word

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
#url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/master/google-10000-english.txt'
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/deekayen/4148741/raw/01c6252ccc5b5fb307c1bb899c95989a8a284616/1-1000.txt'
#data = urlopen(url)
#print('H w')

# it's a file like object and works just like a file
l = set()
data = urlopen(url)
for line in data:  # files are iterable
    word = line.strip()
    print(word)
    l.add(word)

print(l)
```

Comment: If you want you can decode each byte object like this: item.decode('UTF-8')

Comment: Looks like the text file is not only an example. What would you do with a binary file? Please edit the title of the question. I mean: reading a line from a non-text file doesn't make sense

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to decode each **byte** object to **unicode**. For that you can use the method `decode('utf-8')`. Here's the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/deekayen/4148741/raw/01c6252ccc5b5fb307c1bb899c95989a8a284616/1-1000.txt'

l = set()
data = urlopen(url)
for line in data:  # files are iterable
    word = line.strip().decode('utf-8') # decode the line into unicode
    print(word)
    l.add(word)

print(l)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's simple using pandas. Just execute

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/deekayen/4148741/raw/01c6252ccc5b5fb307c1bb899c95989a8a284616/1-1000.txt')
```

and you are all set :)